# A more efficient way of plotting four points, connect them and the color the area under the box in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot four points, each point representing the latitude and longitude of the object. I am trying to plot these four points, connect the first point to the second, second to the third and the third point to the fourth point and the fourth point back to first point. This is my code so far and it works fine but I was wondering if there was a better or efficient way to do it to decrease the plotting time.

```
lat = [20.2,30.2,40.3,50.3]
long = [21.3,22.3,22.7,22.9]
lat = np.append(lat, lat[0])
long = np.append(long, long[0])  
plt.plot(lat, long, "k-", color = 'blue')
plt.fill_between(lat, long, facecolor = 'red' )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us what is inefficient about this solution? All lines are minimal. You can just get rid of numpy by extending your list using `+`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to draw a Polygon. So one alternative is to use `Polygon` to do so.

```
lat = [20.2,30.2,40.3,50.3]
long = [21.3,22.3,22.7,22.9]
lat = np.append(lat, lat[0])
long = np.append(long, long[0])  

plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Polygon(np.c_[lat,long], facecolor = 'red', edgecolor="blue"))
plt.gca().autoscale()
plt.show()
```

Note that this is not more efficient than the solution in the question, just a different option.